# bash.exe can't be found in path in vscode when running javascript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I want to be able to run JavaScript within my visual studio code but I'm having a hard time getting it to work.

Here's the json settings in my visual studio code:

```
{
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\bash.exe",
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized Dark",
"vetur.validation.template": false
}
```

I get the following error when I try to open a 'New Terminal' is VS Code:
**"The terminal shell path "C:\WINDOWS\System32\bash.exe" does not exist"**

As you can see, the bash is in the right location so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have git bash installed? Windows by default doesn't have bash, unless you have WSL installed.

Comment: I do have git bash installed.  I also have WSL

Comment: Can you be more specify with your problem because there is nothing wrong with `bash` which you have already installed but I am guessing that you are facing issues with compiling the `typescript`, so you have to share of what you have done to compile the `typescript` after using `npm` to install it.

Comment: My apologies.  I rewrote the problem.  I was going through a typescript workshop video and they started out with running JavaScript in VS code.  Thanks for any help you can provide.